# Data type mismatch error in boolean

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, oledb

I need to make an authentication on the `VotingStatus(Boolean)` of the user, once that his voting status is checked in the database he shouldn't be able to vote again.

**This code below shows a data type mismatch error. What is wrong with this?**

```
MessageBox.Show("Welcome!");
OleDbCommand comd1 = new OleDbCommand();
comd1.Connection = connection;
comd1.CommandText = "SELECT VoterID FROM tbl_voter where Uname='" + txt_user.Text + "' and Pword='" + txt_pass.Text + "'";
voterid = Convert.ToString(comd1.ExecuteScalar());
Program.VoterID = voterid;

string comd21 = "Select VotingStatus from tbl_voter where VoterID='" + voterid + "'";
OleDbCommand comd2 = new OleDbCommand(comd21, connection);
var vstatus = (String)comd2.ExecuteScalar();
if (vstatus == "true")
{
      MessageBox.Show("You cannot vote again!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the following lines

```
var vstatus = (String)comd2.ExecuteScalar();
if (vstatus == "true")
```

as below:

```
var vstatus = comd2.ExecuteScalar();
if (vstatus !=null && Convert.ToBoolean(vstatus))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You cannot vote again!");
}
```

Despite it is irrelevant with that you have asked, it should be mentioned that you must avoid using string concatenation in the creation of SQL statements. 
Not doing so you are open to SQL injections.

Comment: I need to compare the `VotingStatus` which is boolean with "true/false" in order to check if the voter has already voted.

Comment: The value of `VotingStatus` in database is `true` or `false` as a varchar type?

Comment: what do you mean by varchar type?

Comment: @Theodore what is the type of `VotingStatus` column?

Comment: `VotingStatus` is a Yes/No field.

Comment: @Theodore There isn't any type Yes/No. When you created the table what was the definition of `VotingStatus` column? It should be something like this `VotingStatus BIT NOT NULL` or `Voting Status VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL` etc.

Comment: @Theodore Thanks ! Great this is what I wanted. My bad..since I assumed that you are using MSSQL, as it seems you might use MySQL or another RDBMS that supports the type you mentioned.

Comment: I am using MS Access 2007.